# Avoid installing dependencies each time in a continuous deployment pipeline

Tags: docker, continuous-deployment, aws-codebuild, continuous-delivery

I'm trying to create a continuous deployment pipeline for a Python project.

My Dockerfile uses an Ubuntu base image and installs in top of it the virtual environment for Python and its dependencies based on the requirements file. This way the image always has the Python and dependencies version the project needs.

The problem is that the installation of this dependencies takes too much time (and compute resources that I have to pay in AWS CodeBuild or any other cloud service).

I think one solution could be to have a base image with all the dependencies preinstalled and, if the requirements file varies from the dependencies installed in the base image, update the base image updating or installing only the required dependencies, save this new base image for the next builds and use it for the current build.

This way the build phase will be faster because all the dependencies are preinstalled, and extra build time only will be used when there is a new dependency or a new version of a dependency.

How could I do this?

Comment: Are you asking for AWS CI approaches in particular, or CI solutions in general?

Comment: @halfer I would use the most convinient approach. I know how to use AWS so using CodeBuild is a valid option for me. But I'd like to be informed about all the possible solutions.

Comment: In general, you can have a build that produces your build/CI image, say run weekly, to keep it up to date. You can push it to GitLab or some other Docker registry, from where it can be pulled (either publicly or with authentication). Then in your actual build, you can pull this ready-made image, rather than having to build your build tools. I do this with CircleCI, but I am sure AWS CodeBuild could do it as well.

Comment: I would not worry about downvotes - you received one upvote and one downvote, and both voters will have long gone. It is my experience that people will either comment immediately to give you feedback about a vote, or they won't, and chasing for feedback is generally fruitless. It is only one, so I would ignore it. Note also that voting is anonymous by design, and always will be - in general if you ask spell-checked and structured questions involving obvious prior research, you will get more up than down.

Comment: You could also see if AWS CodeBuild does layer caching - or if not, you can implement it yourself. However this is a bit tricker, and a weekly separate build is what I recommend. However, you can look into layer caching if you like - [I wrote about it here](https://blog.jondh.me.uk/2018/04/strategies-for-docker-layer-caching-in-circleci/).

Comment: Ah, I mentioned GitLab as a Docker registry, but of course AWS will have their own. That likely will be faster for you.

Answer (score 0):

May be using an external cache could work, it uses AWS ECR to cache and reuse the image to build with any new changes. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/reducing-docker-image-build-time-on-aws-codebuild-using-an-external-cache/

Comment: In that case, if a dependency is updated to a new version, the whole layer that contains that dependency will be invalid and not able to reuse from the cache, so all the dependencies will have to be updated again. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. If there is a dependency change it cannot reuse that layer.

Comment: I'd like not having to reinstall all the dependencies and only update the only dependency that changed.